# Не срабатывает скрипт парсер поиска в ютубе

Tags: python

Мои данные:
Python27
Windows XP
Windows 7 Starter
C:\Python27
 ==========================
Пытаюсь запустить скрипт.
Поиск в ютубе. болонская удочка
 ==================================

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import quote
import re, os, sys

def findyoutube(x):
    mas=[]
    sq='http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+quote(x)
    doc = urllib.request.urlopen(sq).read().decode('cp1251',errors='ignore')
    match = re.findall("\?v\=(.+?)\"", doc)
    if not(match is None):
        for ii in match:
            if(len(ii)<25):
                mas.append(ii)
    mas=dict(zip(mas,mas)).values()
    mas2=[]
    for y in mas: mas2.append('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+y)
    return mas2

print(findyoutube('болонская+удочка'))
```

========================================
Ничего в

Comment: У меня ваш код работает правильно - он находит 19 УРЛ: `['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGNxRFe9sHs', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siVtoTQGrK4', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Kp1pyMLJ8c', ...]` Может быть, что файл с вашим скриптом не сохранен в UTF-8; попробуйте поиск чего-то на английском чтобы проверить это.

Comment: Пытался: Pol+Anka -- не работает. Python 2.7.15rc1 (v2.7.15rc1:bad9a580ca, Apr 14 2018, 23:30:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

Comment: У меня нашёл 17 УРЛ - Питон 2 кончит свою жизнь в конце текущего года, попробуйте перейти на версию 3.